# Link to array push function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically why I can't do this:

```
var a = [];
var b = a.push;
b(1);
```

it give's error, I know how to avoid this, but why this is not working in js?

Comment: Because the value of `this` is determined at call time. However, you dissassociate the call from `a`. Therefore, there is no `this` value when `b()` (which is a reference to `Array.prototype.push` is called, so there is nothing to push *to*.

Comment: please post as answer so I will be able to accept it

Answer (score 1):

The `this` value is determined by how the function is called. You can use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to ensure the `this` value is set.

```js
var a = [];
var b = a.push.bind(a);
b(1);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var a = [];
var b = (param) => a.push(param);
b(1);
```